# JSplitPane not filling panel

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, jsplitpane

I am having some trouble with making a `JSplitPane` work how I would like it too.

First, I would like it to fill its container (a JFrame) fully, not have its size determined by the components inside the the split panes. Second, when I resize the container, it does not display the scroll bar on either the `JScrollPane`s or the `JList`s.

Any ideas how to make this happen. I'm sure I just need to wire up some listeners correctly, but I'm not quite sure where to start.

My panel looks something like this...

```
public class MainPanel extends JPanel {
    public MainPanel(){
        JPanel p1 = new JPanel();
        JPanel p2 = new JPanel();
        JPanel p3 = new JPanel();

        p1.setLayout(new BoxLayout(p1, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));
        p2.setLayout(new BoxLayout(p2, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));
        p3.setLayout(new BoxLayout(p3, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));

        p1.add(new SomeButtons());
        p2.add(new SomeButtons());
        p3.add(new SomeButtons());

        p1.add(newNeedyList());
        p2.add(newNeedyList());
        p3.add(newNeedyList());

        Dimension ms = new Dimension(0,0);

        p1.setMinimumSize(ms);
        p2.setMinimumSize(ms);
        p3.setMinimumSize(ms);

        p1.setBackground(Color.red);
        p2.setBackground(Color.green);
        p3.setBackground(Color.blue);



        JScrollPane scp1 = new JScrollPane(p1);
        JScrollPane scp2 = new JScrollPane(p2);
        JScrollPane scp3 = new JScrollPane(p3);

        scp1.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
        scp2.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
        scp3.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);

        scp1.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(
           JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
        scp2.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(
           JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
        scp3.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(
           JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);


        JSplitPane sp1 = new JSplitPane(JSplitPane.HORIZONTAL_SPLIT,scp2,scp3);
        JSplitPane sp2 = new JSplitPane(JSplitPane.HORIZONTAL_SPLIT,scp1,sp1);


        sp1.setDividerLocation(0.5);
        sp2.setDividerLocation(0.333333333);

        sp2.setResizeWeight(0.333333333);
        sp1.setResizeWeight(1.0);

        this.add(sp2, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    }

    /** Some buttons... this part is just to fill the
     panel roughly how I want it look */

    private class SomeButtons extends JPanel{
        public SomeButtons(){
            this.setLayout(new BoxLayout(this, BoxLayout.LINE_AXIS));
            this.add(new JLabel("Stuff:"));
            for(int i=0; i<5; i++){
                final JButton btn = new JButton(" "+i+" ");
                btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(btn,
                                "Feck off!", "You have pressed a button",
                                JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
                    }
                });
                this.add(btn);

            }
        }
    }

    private JList newNeedyList(){
        String[] s = new String[7];
        s[0] = "Choose Me!";
        for (int i=1; i<7; i++){
            s[i] = "No! Choose ME!";
        }
        return new JList(s);
    }
}
```

at the moment I have it in a JFrame

```
public class ThreePanelsTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();

        MainPanel panel = new MainPanel();

        frame.add(panel);

        frame.setSize(1000,600);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        frame.setVisible(true);

    }
}
```

Comment: too hard to says something cleaver because your description  is quite contradictory, my view ---> paint exected output to image,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you don't need to add the MainPanel class, instead, add the components you add into the Mainpanel object directly into the contentPane of the JFrame...

```
final Container contentPane = this.getContentPane();
contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout(2, 2));
```

Comment: +1, yes, the default layout for a JPanel is a FlowLayout. So all components are displayed at their preferred sizes so the split pane will never resize to fill the entire frame. The default layout of a frame is a BorderLayout so you don't need to set the layout, just add the split pane directly to the frame. Or, if you still want to use the MainPanel, then make its layout a BorderLayout.

Comment: @camickr & OP. Thank you both, this is perfect. Adding a `setLayout(new Borderlayout(2,2))` has solved all my problems.

Answer (score 1):

1. everything depends of my comment posted here too hard to says something cleaver because your description is quite contradictory, my view ---> paint exected output to image,

   ---
2. use frame.pack() instead of frame.setSize(1000,600);
3. setDividerLocation() should be wrpapped (delayed) in invokeLater
4. BoxLayout accepting min, max and preferred size, override that,